# Site cleanup - what do we need to do?

Tags: discussion

Let's have a look at the site - are there old policies in meta that we should mark as obsolete? Do the help pages need updating? (We can edit some of them, not all of them.) Any tag wikis that need updating?

Let's do this as one item per answer on this meta page.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend completing the [Welcome to Writers.SE!](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/580/welcome-to-writers-se) page. It was a good idea, which I never got around to.

I feel like the site tour and FAQ pages don't really give newcomers the welcome and introduction they need -- the material is *there*, but they don't know where to look first, or what's important. An intro page -- one explaining our specific nature, and how we differ from other **writing** sites, and pointing to the Meta resources *we've* built up -- would be a real asset.

Answer (score 4):

It could be useful to have somewhere in meta a list of "template" comments, containing links to the relevant pages, for situations that come up often.

Examples: comments for first questions (giving links to the welcome page and help center), for answers given to a blatantly off-topic question, for one-sentence answers, etc.

Comment: I use [SE auto review comments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) for this. But you're right that having a list of suggested phrasings and links could be helpful.

Comment: Good idea.  I also use the auto-review comments and have added some customizations for this site.  (And a couple others where I find myself leaving the same comments over and over.)

Comment: @NeilFein & MonicaCellio Thank you, I didn't know this existed, guess the list should be replaced by a post encouraging reviewers to use it.

Comment: I prefer to write a comment targeted at the specific individual post, but I often use a phrase like "Welcome to xyz.SE! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!" which is written like `Welcome to xyz.SE! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!` See also [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/352819). I also love `[edit]`, `[meta]` and `[help/dont-ask]`. Magic links make writing useful comments *a lot* easier.